# Algolia Horizontally Displayed Menu

Tags: css, algolia

I am using Algolia's InstantSearch.js to power my search results. Using their **menu** refinement (https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/menu/js/), I have built a menu that shows 6 of the most attributed categories in my catalogue, followed by a *Show More* label.

When the menu loads up, it is showing each of the categories in a vertical manner (block formatting of the unordered list items in CSS).

[image: How it is currently showing up]

I would like for it to be displayed in a horizontal layout (inline formatting of the unordered list items in CSS) but cannot seem to get any changes to the styling applied to the menu with regards to positioning of the elements.

[image: How I would like it to show up]

Here is the Algolia template code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{slug}}">
    <span class="{{cssClasses.label}}">{{label}}</span>
    <span class="{{cssClasses.count}}">
    {{#helpers.formatNumber}}{{count}}{{/helpers.formatNumber}}
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

That Algolia code is being rendered this way:

```
<ul class="ais-Menu-list">
  <li class="ais-Menu-item">
    <div>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href=""> <span class="ais-Menu-label">Worksheet / Template</span> <span class="ais-Menu-count tiny-text"> 388 </span> </a> </li>
    </div>
  </li>

  ...

</ul>
```

And I've tried applying styles such as the following but with no luck in it changing the display behaviour of the list items:

```
ul.ais-Menu-list li.ais-Menu-item div li.nav-item,
li.nav-item,
li.nav-item a.nav-link {
  display:inline !important;
}
```

I know that there is the possibility to change the rendering of a widget using **connectors** (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/customize-an-existing-widget/js/#customize-the-complete-ui-of-the-widgets), but I haven't ventured down that path yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [menu live demo](https://instantsearchjs.netlify.com/stories/?selectedStory=Menu.default), setting this does work:

```
li.ais-Menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: inlined]
[image]

`inline` doesn't though, but it shouldn't be a big deal?

If it doesn't work for you it might be worth checking out your CSS loading order/what overrides your own styles.

Comment: You know, I thought I had tried that! Doh! Thanks so much for the response. Works as I needed. :)